# mergeReleaseResources Failed, caused of `not valid resource name` (Version from package.json)

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, package.json

I do an require for package.json in my React-Native-App to read the Version-Number from there to display it in my App:

```
const pjson = require('../../package.json');
```

Caused of this, I got an error while bundling an RELEASE APK in Android with gradle:

> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
>   /home/Projekte/APP/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/package.json: Error: package is not a valid resource name (reserved Java keyword)

Is there a way to exclude this package.json from the Process who merge the Resources for the APK?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to update to `react-native 0.61.x`.
The whole solution can be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/metro/pull/420).

Where's what's causing the issue, taken from the above link:

> cli will copy files with json extension to resource dir, in Android's
>   case, android/app/build/res.
>
> Here comes a problem. If package.json at the project root gets copied,
>   it won't be renamed as other package.json in node_modules (e.g.
>   raw/node_modules_reactnativecodepush_package.json). Instead, it will
>   reside in res as package.json, which causes the error:
>
> android/app/src/main/res/raw/package.json: Error: package is not a
>   valid resource name (reserved Java keyword)

If you can't update, it's possible to apply a patch directly to your `node_modules/metro` module that excludes `package.json` from the bundle release process.

The patch:
on file `node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Serializers/getAssets.js`, on line 66, replace

`getJsOutput(module).type === "js/module/asset"`

by

`getJsOutput(module).type === "js/module/asset" && path.relative(options.projectRoot, module.path) !== "package.json"`

OR

add the following file to the root of your project,

```
// fix_metro_android_release_bug.js
// Temporary fix for this issue: https://github.com/facebook/metro/pull/420
const fs = require('fs');

const fileLocation = './node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Serializers/getAssets.js';
const targetText = 'getJsOutput(module).type === "js/module/asset"';
const replacementText = 'getJsOutput(module).type === "js/module/asset" && path.relative(options.projectRoot, module.path) !== "package.json"';

const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(fileLocation, 'utf8');
if (fileContent.includes(targetText) && !fileContent.includes(replacementText)) {
    const patchedFileContent = fileContent.replace(targetText, replacementText);
    fs.writeFileSync(fileLocation, patchedFileContent, 'utf8');
}
```

and add the following snippet to your `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "babel-node ./fix_metro_android_release_bug.js",
    ...
  }
```